# onClose on p-calendar won't trigger

Tags: angular, primeng

I'am using primeng components `p-calendar` and `p-table`. The workflow is this following:  I have two `p-calendar` in `p-table` row. The issue is when I click over the 'second' `p-calendar` the `onClose()`method won't trigger, it only get trigged when I click outside the `p-table` first.
Below my code :

```
<p-table [value]="list" [style]="{width: '60%', 'text-align': 'center'}">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
<tr>
  <th scope="col">libelle</th>
  <th scope="col">date debut</th>
  <th scope="col">date fin</th>
</tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-element>
<tr>
  <!-- colonne libelle -->
  <td pEditableColumn>
    <p-cellEditor>
      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
        <div class="ui-inputgroup">
          <input pInputText type="text" style="text-align: center"
                 class="form-control"
                 [(ngModel)]="data.libelle">
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="output" style="text-align: center">
        {{ element?.libelle}}
      </ng-template>
    </p-cellEditor>
  </td>

  <!-- colonne date debut-->
  <td pEditableColumn>
    <p-cellEditor>
      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
        <div class="ui-inputgroup">
          <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="element.dateDebut" [timeOnly]="true"
                      (onClose)="validerHeureDebut(element)"></p-calendar>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="output">
        <div>
          {{ element?.dateDebut | date:'HH:mm'}}
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-cellEditor>
  </td>

  <!-- colonne date fin-->
  <td pEditableColumn>
    <p-cellEditor>
      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
        <div class="ui-inputgroup">
          <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="element.dateFin" [timeOnly]="true"
                      (onClose)="validerHeureFin(element)"></p-calendar>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="output">
        <div>
          {{ element?.dateFin | date:'HH:mm'}}
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-cellEditor>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjwfvm)

Comment: Not enough, provide a stackbliz at least.

Comment: @selemmn done (sorry to be late)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was solved after removing `pEditableColumn` and `<p-cellEditor>`